# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type SplFileInfo as array

Tags: php, zen-cart

I want to get all images from folder `/folder/floder2` and then check whether these Images exists in the DB or not, and then delete if it does not exist in DB

below is my code -

```
$imgarray= array();

function rsearch() {
    global $imgarray;
    $directory= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/folder1';
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));

    foreach($objects as $name){
        $imgarray[] = $name;
    }
}

$files = rsearch(); 

foreach ($dbArray as $dbImg ) {
    $Img = trim($dbImg['products_image'],"products/"); 

    foreach ($imgarray as $folderImg) {
        $ignore = Array(".", "..");

        if($Img == $folderImg){
            echo 'success';
        }else {
            unlink($folderImg);
            echo 'successfully deleted';
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting below type of when `print_r($folderImg);`

```
SplFileInfo Object ( 
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /var/www/vhosts/serverfoldername/project.com/projectfolder/folder/folder1/image1.jpg 
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => image1.jpg 
)
```

I want to print this to print

```
[fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => image1.jpg
```

but i am not getting how to call this type of

```
Array ( 
    [0] => SplFileInfo Object ( 
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /var/www/vhosts/serverfoldername/project.com/projectfolder/folder/folder1/image1.jpg 
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => image1.jpg 
    ) 
    [1] => SplFileInfo Object ( 
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /var/www/vhosts/serverfoldername/project.com/projectfolder/folder/folder1/imag2.png
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => imag2.png 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the filename of a SplFileInfo Object  http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

```
print_r($folderImg->getFilename()):
```